# Keep track of the children in the parent, or keep track of the parent in the children?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So let's say I'm creating a list with sections.

Is it preferred to keep an `Array` of `ObjectId`'s in the parent element.

```
var listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     sections : {type: [ObjectId], ref : "Section"}
});
```

Or do I just keep a reference to the parent's `ObjectId` in each item and simply find

```
var sectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     list : {type: ObjectId, ref : "List"}
});
```

(Or both for maximum flexibility?)

I've been doing the second way, but I'm thinking I might be too stuck in the relational DB paradigm. Because once there are multiple levels of nesting it seems to get pretty dirty with all the callbacks to get the data I want. And I don't really get to take advantage of the populate function.

Comment: This basic question has been covered a LOT both on StackOverflow and elsewhere. It's common enough that 10gen has documented the various pros and cons of the options: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tree+structure+mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each object only has 1 parent, it's much easier to keep the parent ID in the child object.

Although, if you're always trying to find the children of an object, rather than the parent, then it would be easier to store an array of children IDs in the parent object.

I'm not sure of the availability of Maps in the language you're using, but youcan use Maps to link parent IDs to children IDs. It works by storing a parent ID as the key, and the child ID as the value. This way, all you have to do is look up the parent ID and get all its values, or look up the child ID and get its parent.

This means the IDs are not stored in either the child or parent, but in a separate data structure that they'll both need access to.

Also, a regular Map may only allow one value per key. If this is the case, you need a MultiMap. There's probably some info on the internet somewhere about how to use it and how to get access to the class.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're commenting when you don't even know the technology?